# MVC4 Forum with simplemembership

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Does anyone know any open source forum that works with mvc4 SimpleMembership and is easly configurable or have any tutorials on how to create your own mvc4 forum?

Comment: Why specifically with SimpleMembership?

Answer (score 0):

> create your own mvc4 forum?

http://www.mvcforum.com/ that should work for you. Easily customizable, pluggable architecture.